# Swagger annotations for fixed set of Strings for input

Tags: java, annotations, swagger

Currently I have API which have something like below

```
    @GetMapping("/list/{type}")
    @ApiOperation(nickname = "reportUnits", httpMethod = "GET", produces = "application/json", responseContainer = "List", response = ReportFormatDTO.class, value = "Returns all available report Units", notes = "Returns all available report Units", consumes = "text")
    @ApiResponses({ @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "No data found"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Error getting Report Units"), })
    Flux<ReportFormatDTO> getList(@PathVariable("type") String type);
```

I need to tell swagger about fixed set of String to be passed in the Path variable.